# Jerky mouse movements

Tags: unity, xorg

As the Title indicates I have some problem with delicate movement of the mouse in Ubuntu fresh installation.

The jerkiness is shown more at small and slow movements when the mouse will move a 2 millimeters to any random positions every 5 centimeters of movements. My mouse is a Microsoft Sidewinder Gaming mouse.

Is there any driver I can use to fix it or any configuration? This is happening both in Unity or inside games and programs.

Comment: i have the same problem, what exactly did you change?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may try this to check mouse parameters :

Open a terminal and Run this command:

```
xinput --list --short
```

output :

```
abcd@abcd-abcde:~$ xinput --list --short

Virtual core pointer

↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

↳ Logitech USB RECEIVER                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

for me my pointing devices are a Lgitech usb reciver and synaptic touchpad

To list out device Properties :

```
xinput --list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

check properties like acceleration deceleration and see if they seam allright:

if you need to change any value like suppose this one :

```
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):   2.500000
```

using this command :

```
xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5
```

You may have to play around with this number a bit to set it exactly as you need.

If you need to set this value automatically every time Ubuntu starts then :

create a .sh file

```
 #!/bin/sh

 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5
```

change the file to executable :

```
 chmod +x
```

and Put this in the start-up applications list.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the mouse settings via the GUI, I found they were set to lowest possible acceleration, and lowest possible sensitivity. So I changed them using the GUI app and so far it's working just fine (after 5 mins)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Pointing Devices in the software center and use settings there (it has a GUI). My mouse has since calmed down.

Answer (score 1):

My Dell Inspiron One has a touch screen, I disabled it and now my mouse is behaving normally. If your computer has a touch screen try disabling it or adjusting the sensitivity.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a sufficient answer. It could only works if people have a touch screen, but in the question is not mentioned. Next time, please read with care the question.

Comment: Good grief, why so pedantic? Maybe the OP has a touch screen but never thought it was relevant? Besides, I *do* have a touch screen and this answer was helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just the mouse itself malfunctioning. Sometimes it's not in software.